# Is there a way to disable Component Testing feature in cypress 10.x and above

Tags: cypress, cypress-component-test-runner

We do not use the Component Testing feature in Cypress, which was introduced in version 10.x and above. Its an additional burden to close it every time before we land into the test runner.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [the `--e2e` flag](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/command-line#cypress-open) when running Cypress via command line to launch directly to the end-to-end test suite. Assuming you're using `npm`, that would be:

```
npx cypress open --e2e
```

If you have a `package.json` file where you store your scripts, you can modify that script as well.

```
...
"cypress:open": "npx cypress open --e2e",
...
npm run cypress:open
```